# CSS Positioning After Using Float

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Gmail</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Images</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-dots" href="#"><img src="./img/dots.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a id="sign-in" href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <section id="google-logo">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Google Logo">
    </div>
  </section>
```

Hi guys, I am trying to replicate the Google homepage and have ran into a problem positioning the Google logo. You can see from my CSS below that I used float:right to position the navbar, but now when I try to style the Google logo it has it placed upon the same line as the navbar. Therefore when I center it for example, it's centered between the navbar and the left margin. I want this to position as a block underneath.

CSS below:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:Arial;
}

/*GLOBAL */
.container {
  width:96%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

/* NAV */
nav {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

nav li {
  display:inline;
}

nav .nav-link {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

nav #nav-dots {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 18px 0 10px;
}

nav #sign-in {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4787ED;
  padding: 7px 12px 8px 12px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#google-logo {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `clear:both;` property on #google-logo.

```
   #google-logo {
        clear:both;
    }
```

Clear both will break a non floated element from a floated element in a "display:block" type of way.

Comment: brilliant! Knew it would be a simple one liner!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating the nav, use the position attribute. 
Example with your code:

```
nav { position: absolute; top: 17px; right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add to your CSS:

```
.container:after{
   content:"";
   clear: both;
 }
```

And you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

> The clear property is directly related to floats. If the element can
>   fit horizontally in the space next to another element which is
>   floated, it will. Unless you apply clear to that element in the same
>   direction as the float. Then the element will move down below the
>   floated element.

```
 #google-logo {
        clear:both;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-css -->
     body {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      font-family:Arial;
    }

    /*GLOBAL */
    .container {
      width:96%;
      margin:auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul {
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }

    /* NAV */
    nav {
      float: right;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 17px;
    }

    nav li {
      display:inline;
    }

    nav .nav-link {
      text-decoration:none;
      color: #222;
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: 0.02em;
      margin-right: 7px;
    }

    nav #nav-dots {
      position: relative;
      top: 5px;
      margin: 0 18px 0 10px;
    }

    nav #sign-in {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #4787ED;
      padding: 7px 12px 8px 12px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .clear {
       clear: both;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

     <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Gmail</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Images</a></li>
            <li><a id="nav-dots" href="#"><img src="./img/dots.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a id="sign-in" href="#">Sign in</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
      <section id="google-logo">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Google Logo">
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide extra information explain how it answers the question?

Comment: you can follow this link

http://markupboy.com/blog/banishing-lt-div-class-clear-gt/

Comment: Please read the help center section about answering questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .